# Mixing 9-speed Tiagra and 9-speed Deore XT

Tags: gears, shimano, cassette

I currently have a road bike with the following setup for the gears:

9-speed Tiagra front and rear derailleurs, Sora shifters, all from 2009:
30/39/52 Crankset
11-25 Cassette.

I need some more low gears for hilly areas, and I am thinking of switching to a 9-speed Deore XT derailleur and 11-32 cassette. Is it possible / compatible? Do you think that cross-chaining would be an issue? Will I need a new chain?

Comment: See related question: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/11101/9-speed-road-sti-mtb-derailleur

Comment: Also: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/10056/can-i-fit-a-cassette-with-a-larger-range-with-my-shimano-tiagra-10-speed-gs-46

Comment: Yes, always put on a new chain when you change the cassette.

Comment: I just installed the setup that I mentioned in my question: Deore XT long cage, 11-32 cassette and new chain. It works well. There is slight cross-chaining in the large-cog/large-chainring and small cog/small chainring, but I was expecting it. I'll never use that combination anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that will work just fine. I have a similar setup on my touring bike, Tiagra shifters and an LX derailleur.

Comment: Yep, so long as it's all 9-speed it should be fine.  10 speed mountain stuff uses different pull ratios and may have issues with road shifters.